# Looking for some code to write .gif or .png files (not libpng)

Tags: c, png, gif

I am working at a very minimalistic web server that gets the data from a microcontroller and will output some simple charts. That server will possibly run on embedded devices, and I would like to keep the code as small as possible, and ideally without dependencies.
I don't want to end up using libpng (and zlib), so I was wondering if anyone has or knows some little code to write a plain png or gif (palleted, no compression).

Comment: PNG always has compression, it practically requires zlib

Comment: "There is no uncompressed variant of PNG. It is possible to store uncompressed data by using only uncompressed deflate blocks (a feature normally used to guarantee that deflate does not make incompressible data much larger)."

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, but I have used [LodePNG](http://lodev.org/lodepng/) for just this.

It's a single C90 file(plus header) and has no zlib or libpng dependencies.  It also has a lot of #define's for stripping even smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly run the plotting on the client by using something like [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) instead.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like Flot, but ideally I would like to generate my own images, because there is more flexibility.

Comment: [This](http://alexfru.narod.ru/codequal/CodeQuality.html) is a working GIF encoder/decoder, with compression. You can use it as a reference.